# Cron to report time at whole hour

Tags: cron

I wrote three `report_time` to cron jobs

```
## Report time
*/1 6-23 * * * /home/me/Music/src/report_time.py &> /dev/null


## Report time 2
*/1 6-23 * * *  cvlc /home/me/Music/audio/bell.wav &> /dev/null

## report time
*/1 6-23 * * *  vlc /home/me/Music/audio/bell.wav &> /dev/null
```

However, non of them works as expected, they are all of mute and silence.

What' s the problem?

Comment: Redirect the errors (and outputs) to a log file and see what it says. FYI unless you have arranged otherwise, cron jobs will be run using `sh` - which doesn't understand `&>` as a stdout+stderr redirection - use `> log 2>&1` instead

Comment: cvlc and vlc are both w/o a directory. why?